# missing '@end' error on build react-native App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am trying to upgrade my react-native app to V0.59.8, I followed all steps according to rn-diff repo  https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.4...version/0.59.8

My App work just fine on Android but I have some issue building my App on ios
I am getting a syntax error from `main.m` file  which I don't even touch it

main.m file:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

Error :
[image]

Comment: This might be caused by a problem with `AppDelegate.h`. Are you missing an `@end` there?

Comment: Thanks man missing @end on AppDelegate.h  is the source problem

Comment: It's always better to copy the *text* of the error into your question than to post a screenshot, which can be hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by a missed @end on AppDelegate.h. thanks @rmaddy